# What is the proper way to populate an array of Strings in C, such that each string is a single element in the array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to initialize a 2D array of strings in C; which does not seem to work like any other language I've coded in. What I'm TRYING to do, is read input, and take all of the comments out of that input and store them in a 2d array, where each string would be a new row in the array. When I get to a character that is next line, I want to advance the first index of the array so that I can separate each "comment string". ie.

```
   char arr[100][100];

   <whatever condition>
   arr[i][j] = "//First comment";
```

Then when I get to a '/n' I want to increment the first index such that:

```
   arr[i+1][j] = "//Second comment";
```

I just want to be able to access each input as an individual element in my array. In Java I wouldn't need to do this, as each string would already be an individual element in a String array. I've only been working with c for 3 weeks now, and things that I used to take for granted as being simple, have proven to be quite frustrating in C.

My actual code is below. It gives me an infinite loop and prints out a ton of numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAXLENGTH = 500;

int main(){
    char comment[MAXLENGTH][MAXLENGTH];
    char activeChar;
    int cIndex = 0;
    int startComment = 0;
    int next = 0;

    while((activeChar = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(activeChar == '/'){
            startComment = 1;
        }

        if(activeChar == '\n'){
            comment[next][cIndex] = '\0';
            next++;
        }

        if(startComment){
            comment[next][cIndex] = activeChar;
            cIndex++;
        }
    }

    for(int x = 0 ; x <  MAXLENGTH; x++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXLENGTH; j++){
            if(comment[x][j] != 0)
            printf("%s", comment[x][j]); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not have string objects like other languages. It has [string manipulation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling), but the string itself is just an array of characters with a nul terminator at the end.

Comment: Step by step. Forget processing each string for now - focus on reading them into the array and then printing. Next step, make a simple change to each, and print. And so on. And please don't overlook `fgets()`. It can be simpler processing each string *after* it has been read.

Comment: `char arr[100][100];` is a 2D array of `char`s, single characters, not strings, but one row of it, like `arr[i]`, if null terminated, can be printed as a string with `printf("%s\n", arr[i]);` or inputted with scanf or better fgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that C was designed to be essentially a glorified assembler. That means that the only stuff it has 'built-in' are things for which there is an obvious correct way to do it. Strings do **not** meet this criteria. As such strings are not a first-order citizen in c.

In particular there are at least three viable ways to deal with strings, C doesn't force you to use any of them, but instead allows you to use what you want for the job at hand.

## Method 1: Static Array

This method appears to be similar to what you are trying to do, and is often used by new C programmers. In this method a string is just an array of characters exactly long enough to fit its contents. Assigning arrays becomes difficult, so this promotes using strings as immutables. It feels likely that this is how most JVM's would implement strings. C code: `char my_string[] = "Hello";`

## Method 2: Static Bounded Array

This method is what you are doing. You decide that your strings must be shorter than a specified length, and pre-allocate a large enough buffer for them. In this case it is relatively easy to assign strings and change them, but they must not become longer than the set length. C code: `char my_string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = "Hello";`

## Method 3: Dynamic Array

This is the most advanced and risky method. Here you dynamically allocate your strings so that they always fit their content. If they grow too big, you resize. They can be implemented many ways (usually as a single char pointer that is realloc'd as necessary in combination with method 2, occasionally as a linked list).

Regardless of how you implement strings, to C's eyes they are all just arrays of characters. The only caveat is that to use the standard library you need to null terminate your strings manually (although many [all?] of them specify ways to get around this by manually specifying the length).

This is why java strings are not primitive types, but rather objects of type `String`.

Interestingly enough, many languages actually use different String types for these solutions. For example Ada has `String`, `Bounded_String`, and `Unbounded_String` for the three methods above.

## Solution

Look at your code again: `char arr[100][100];` which method is this, and what is it?

Obviously it is method 2 with `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` of 100. So you could pretend the line says: `my_strings arr[100]` which makes your issue apparent, this is not a 2D array of strings, but a 2D array of characters which represents a 1D array of strings. To create a 2D array of strings in C you would use: `char arr[WIDTH][HEIGHT][MAX_STRING_LENGTH]` which is easy to get wrong. As above, however, you have some logic errors in your code, and you can probably solve this problem with just a 1D array of strings. (2D array of chars)

Comment: it might be helpful to use a typedef to separate the 'string' part of the 3D char array type from the array part

Comment: You forgot to mention that in C strings are zero-terminated. So `char my_string[] = "Hello";` will generate an array of length 6, not 5.

Comment: Easier - yes, helpful - not in my opinion. I think it goes against the philosophy of C to hide implementation details that way. It can easily lead to awkwardness with EG: `typedef char string[MAX_STRING_SIZE]; string a = "test"; string b = "test2"; a = b;` you expect that would actually work because a seems to have a primitive type, but that is not the case. This is the same reason why it is unwise to do `typedef struct { ... } mystruct;`.

Comment: C strings are not zero-terminated if you don't want them to be, I made that clear. As such `char my_string[5] = "Hello";` is completely valid and just won't have the null terminator on the end. There is no rule against this at all. C merely 'plays nicely' with null-terminated strings. Unlike other languages it doesn't forbid much at all, including how you want to use strings.

Comment: "Hello" is a six element constant; that example doesn't compile (at least in MSVC)

Comment: If they are not zero terminated, they are plain char arrays, not "strings".

Comment: @zacaj right you are, I forgot that that is an extension (I used it once, forgot how I got it working, probably some esoteric gcc extension).

Comment: @Bob__ A string is any representation of text. If you store strings via ints with ascii values, good for you, still a string, just not a "c-string" which is indeed null terminated (because of the way c default its initialization).

Answer (score 1):

comment is a 2D array of chars, which are single characters.  In C, a string is simply an array of characters, so your definition of comment is one way to define a 1D array of strings.

As far as the loading goes, the only obvious potential problem is that you don't ever reset startComment to zero (but you should use a debugger to make sure it's being loaded correctly), however your code to print it out is wrong.

Using printf() with a %s tells it to start printing the string at whatever address you give it, but you're giving it individual characters, not whole strings, so it's interpreting each character in each string (because C is a horrible, horrible language) as an address in RAM and trying to print that RAM.  To print an individual character, use %c instead of %s.  Or, just make a 1D for loop:

```
for(int x=0; x<MAX_LENGTH; X++)
    printf("%s\n", comment[x])
```

It's also a bit confusing that you use the same MAX_LENGTH for the number of lines in the array and the length of the string in each line

Comment: Qualify "In C, a string is simply an array of characters". No, what makes that array a string in C is the `'\0'` terminator.